# kde4 got funny transparent background

Tags: gentoo, kde-4

My system is Gentoo amd64, updated to the latest. After I updated and restarted my computer, I got this funny transparent [background](https://twitpic.com/c4b8iu), but only in popup dialogs/menus. I *have tried to delete the ~/.kde4 dictionary and restart my computer. But no luck.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it is solved automatically...I have no idea how it happened :(

Probably, it has something to do with the *kdewallet*. I did not enable the wallet previously, because I do not think it is useful and required. But I could not even connect to my WIFI if it is disabled. So I enabled and configured the *KDEWallet*, then the background issue resolved :)